# How do I use "DOES NOT CONTAIN" with \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface?

Tags: 8, database

I have a node with a list field of text values. I want to write a query that gets all nodes that don't have one of the selected values.

How do I write this query?

```
$query->condition('field_states_excluded', $state, 'DOES NOT CONTAIN');
```

Comment: Slightly sleep-deprived so I might be missing something - isn't that a `NOT IN`? Assuming `$state` is an array

Comment: Sounds like a NOT IN to me as well assuming $state is an array of multiple states.. It only gets complicated when you only want to filter out nodes that match/don't match on *all* of multiple values. Or a partial string match, aka the opposite of "CONTAIN", that would be tricky. But that seems unlikely when talking about states...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [NOT REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) if we assume that `$state` is an array of multiple states.

I will explain with example:
for example if want to get all nodes with the **field title** **DOES NOT  CONTAIN** `page`, `hello`, and `test`.

**Sql statement** should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_field_data` WHERE `type` = 'page' AND `title`  NOT REGEXP '^.*page.*$|^.*hello.*$|^.*test.*$';
```

**Drupal Code**:

```
  $excluded_strings = array('page', 'hello', 'test');
  //- Add regex prefix and suffix
  $excluded_strings_with_regex = array_map(function ($val) {
    return '^.*' . $val . '.*$';
  }, $excluded_strings);
  //- Join array elements with a string | glue 
  //- result $regex_p_string = "^.*page.*$|^.*hello.*$|^.*test.*$"
  $regex_p_string = implode("|", $excluded_strings_with_regex);
  //-Build Query
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
  $query->condition('status', 1);
  $query->condition('type', 'page');
  //- Add regex Condition.
  $query->condition('title', $regex_p_string, 'NOT REGEXP');
  $nids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Returns with Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/QueryException with message 'Invalid condition operator.'

Answer (score 2):

The only operators supported by [`QueryInterface::condition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.6.x) are the following:

- `=`, `<>`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `STARTS_WITH`, `CONTAINS`, `ENDS_WITH`
- `IN`, `NOT IN`
- `BETWEEN`

You cannot use `NOT REGEXP`, since Drupal 8 doesn't support it, but you can use NOT IN, as @Clive and @Berdir suggested, if you have an array of values the field should not have.
Since you are talking of states, I agree with @Berdir it's more probable that is your case. I think more difficult somebody would exclude states (which are a limited set of values) using regular expressions.

Comment: Note that `NOT IN` means "has a value but it isn't contained in the given array. A query using this condition would not match entities have no value in the `field_states_excluded`.

Comment: That's probably true for any operator Drupal supports. For adding in the result also those entities without a value for that field it's sufficient to add a condition more.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `NOT LIKE`.

Entity Query version:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
 ->condition('field_states_excluded', "%" . $database->escapeLike($state) . "%", 'NOT LIKE');
$node__ids = array_values($query->execute());
```

Raw Database query - by title.

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$result = $database->select('node_field_data', 'n')
  ->fields('n', ['nid', 'title'])
  ->condition('title', "%" . $database->escapeLike($state) . "%", 'NOT LIKE')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
$node_ids = array_keys($result);
```

Raw Database query - by a field value.

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$field_name = 'field_states_excluded';
$query = $database->select('node_field_data', 'n')
    ->fields('n', ['nid', 'title']);
$query->join("node__{$field_name}", 'field', 'n.nid = field.entity_id');
$result = $query->condition("field.{$field_name}_value", "%" . $database->escapeLike($state) . "%", 'NOT LIKE')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
$node_ids = array_keys($result);
```